# Connecting to multiple XServers

Tags: x11, xinput

I've got a simple xserver setup:
Ubuntu workstation running xserver, to which a remote Beaglebone computer running linuxcnc is connecting.
So I'm using the mouse, keyboard and screen of the workstation to control the linuxcnc application.

The machines are physically standing next to eachother, but I find that the controls of linuxcnc are a bit laggy...

Therefore, I wonder if it is possible to attach a mouse and keyboard to the Beaglebone directly, and only use the screen of the workstation to display the application.
It would look like this (adapted from the basic schema on Wikipedia):
[image: wanted configuration]

I didn't find any description of this, so I guess it's not possible? I don't know really how xserver internals work, but I can imagine that the mouse needs information about the screen to send relative position events... For the keyboard I can't imagine what the problem could be, somehow I should be able to forward the keystrokes from the remote keyboard to the application, no?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done, but not as drawn, and would probably not offer the advantages you seek.

In a standard x server the display and the keyboard are both physically attached. the exceptions are nesting servers like Xnest, dummy servers without display or input, converters like Xvnc, and one real weird one.

the distributed multihead X server is an X server without a display, It uses multiple X servers for display. It can however have a keyboard and mouse.